# ReactJs, How can I add class name to Map of same divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

this is my code i'm trying to add a class on click to a clicked div but i have more than 1 div have the same classname so when i click to any
div the toggle class added to all divs not the one which i clicked what i want to know how can i specify the div which i want to add toggle class to it

Code:

````js
    const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);
    const toggleClass = () => {
        setActive(!isActive)
        console.log('sad')
    }


    return (
        <div className="command_wrapper">
            <div className="command_list">
                {
                    Commands.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div className="command" >
                                <div className="command_face" onClick={toggleClass}>
                                    <h1>{item.Command}</h1>
                                    <p>{item.Description}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div className={isActive ? "command_body" : "disapper"}>
                                    <div className="command_usage">
                                        <h1>Usage</h1>
                                        <p>{item.Usage}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="command_required">
                                        <h1>Required Permissions</h1>
                                        <p>{item.premissions}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })

                }
            </div>
        </div>
    ```
````

Comment: You can make the separate component for Command item and put the useState logic there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the item inside toggle function and verify if item passed is activated or just save the item clicked.

````
const [itemActive, setItemActive] = useState();
const toggleClass = (item) => {
    setItemActive(item)
}


return (
    <div className="command_wrapper">
        <div className="command_list">
            {
                Commands.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="command" >
                            <div className="command_face" onClick={() => toggleClass(item)}>
                                <h1>{item.Command}</h1>
                                <p>{item.Description}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className={item === itemActive ? "command_body" : "disapper"}>
                                <div className="command_usage">
                                    <h1>Usage</h1>
                                    <p>{item.Usage}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="command_required">
                                    <h1>Required Permissions</h1>
                                    <p>{item.premissions}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                })

            }
        </div>
    </div>
```
````

If item has any unique property, you can save just then, like an ID or name. I think it will be better.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);
const toggleClass = () => {
    setActive(!isActive)
    console.log('sad')
}*/
function handleClick(el){
  //toggle the class which indicates selection ex. 'active'
    el.classList.toggle('active');
 //other stuff todo

}
return (
    <div className="command_wrapper">
        <div className="command_list">
            {
                Commands.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="command" >
                            //destruct event objet{event.target}
                            <div onClick={({target})=>handleClick(target)}>
                                <h1>{item.Command}</h1>
                                <p>{item.Description}</p>
                            </div>
                         ....
                         ...
                        </div>
                    )
                })

            }
        </div>
    </div>
```